# Submitting Ajax Form with Codeigniter - site is hanging + 500 error

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

So I'm pretty sure my problem doesn't lie with the ajax function, as it worked prior. I believe the problem steams from the actual model. SO I'll post this...it seems quite long and I may be doing something wrong, so let's start there...

Okay, so if I remove the following code from the model, the ajax form submits as it should. No issues. But if I leave this code in there, all that happens is the loading icon will appear, won't go away, and the page doesn't shift to the next step. I'm getting an `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` that points to my model.

Anything stand out?

```
// Add or update campaign on database
public function add_campaign() 
{        
    // grab campaign session data
    $id = $this -> session -> userdata('user_name');
    $campaign = $this -> session -> userdata('campaign_name');
    $website = $this -> session -> userdata('campaign_user_website');
    $headline = $this -> session -> userdata('campaign_headline');
    $bar_color = $this -> session -> userdata('campaign_bar_color');
    $head_color = $this -> session -> userdata('campaign_head_color');
    $main_color = $this -> session -> userdata('campaign_main_color');
    $thanks_msg = $this -> session -> userdata('campaign_thanks');        

    //grab scorecard options
    $email_q = $this -> input -> post('email');
    $brand_q = $this -> input -> post('brand');
    $design_q = $this -> input -> post('design');
    $usability_q = $this -> input -> post('usability');
    $support_q = $this -> input -> post('support');
    $service_q = $this -> input -> post('service');
    $recommend_q = $this -> input -> post('recommend');
    $suggestion_q = $this -> input -> post('suggestion');
    $comments_q = $this -> input -> post('comments');

    $created =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s');        

    // insert OR if campaign already exists, update the campaign values and date modified
    $this -> db -> query("
        INSERT INTO campaigns (id, campaign, website, headline, bar_color, head_color, main_color, thanks_msg, email_q, brand_q, design_q, usability_q, support_q, service_q, recommend_q, suggestion_q, comments_q, created)
        VALUES ('$id', '$campaign', '$website', '$headline', '$bar_color', '$head_color', '$main_color', '$thanks_msg', '$email_q', '$brand_q', '$design_q', '$usability_q', '$support_q', '$service_q', '$recommend_q' '$suggestion_q', '$comments_q', '$created',)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE campaign='$campaign', modified='$created'
        ");
}
```

**MORE INFO FOR THOSE WHO NEED IT**

CONTROLLER FUNCTION:

```
public function embed_step()
{
    //Create campaign on database       
    $this -> build_model -> add_campaign();     

    $data['embed_view'] = 'partials/embed'; // display view

    if ($this -> input -> post('ajax')) // is 'ajax' variable from jQuery function exists, load:
    {


        $this -> load -> view($data['embed_view'], $data); 
        //$this->session->unset_userdata('user_url'); // kill session data          
    }
}
```

AJAX FUNCTION (portion):

```
    var score_options = {
        email: $('.email_score').val(),
        brand: $('.brand_score').val(),
        design: $('.design_score').val(),
        usability: $('.usability_score').val(),
        support: $('.support_score').val(),
        service: $('.service_score').val(),
        recommend: $('.recommend_score').val(),
        suggestion: $('.suggestion_score').val(),
        comments: $('.comments_score').val(),
        ajax : '1' // needed for controller, to verify that request is ajax
    };

    //display ajax loader animation
    $('#loading').show();

    $.ajax({
        url : 'ajax/embed_step',
        type : 'POST',
        data : score_options,
        success : function(msg) {
            $('.wizardContent').html(msg);
            // output success in this container             
            $.scrollTo(0, 500);
            // scroll to top on success 
            $('#loading').hide();
            // hide loading icon
        }
    });

    return false;
```

**VIEW INPUT EXAMPLE (ALL ARE THE SAME, MINUS NAME AND CLASS, ETC)**

```
<!-- Scorecard options -->
<div class="scordOption roundtop">
    <div class="checkicon"><input type="checkbox" name="email" class="email_score" value="1"></div>
    <div class="scoreOptionTxt">What is your email address?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use Firebug to see the actual error message from CodeIgniter. It will tell you *exactly* what is wrong.

Comment: FYI, You *should* sanitize your query. This one is vulnerable to SQL Injection

Comment: make a favor replace all your **$this->input->post('something');** with **$this->input->post('something',true);**

Comment: then it seems your request fails, so you need to check if the url given is correct, are you using htaccess to remove **index.php** also?

Comment: @JohnConde Not familiar with Firebug deeply, but The error is not appearing in the console like it does with Chrome...

Comment: @Touki Thanks, I'll look into that once I crunch out this issue.

Comment: @Ispuk I'll replace as requested...I have other forms that work just fine with my method above. I'll give it a shot though...and yes, I removed the index.php in the htaaccess :)

Comment: Nothing...still no dice. Though I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "clicking URL given is correct".

Comment: @MikeBarwick can you navigate by browser that url?

Comment: I'm running through ajax...there's no direct page for the controller function...sort of. Here I'll post my ajax and controller function.

Comment: Added more code...if you think I should upload view...holla. I'm pretty sure I just missed a spot somewhere... stupid error. Just can't find it...

Comment: @Ispuk but yes, I can navigate there. Just shows a blank page though. No 404 if that's what your wondering.

Comment: @MikeBarwick well seems everythings ok so strange .. mm.. what about htaccess? can you paste that too? sorry but i can't figured out what's happening for 500 server error, the code seems ok

Comment: Sure...I'll post. But it's pretty simple HTA file. Certain it's not the problme here. Maybe it's the database set-up...? How can I print what I have via PhpMyAdmin

Comment: `RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: ok sec i'll add to my answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20005/discussion-between-ispuk-and-mike-barwick)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this please in your ajax call?

```
var _ajax_url = "<?php echo site_url('ajax/embed_step'); ?>";

 url : _ajax_url
```

also try this **.htaccess** out, for me it works on many hosts:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: @MikeBarwick you can define **var _ajax_url**  somewhere in the html or in a **config.js** file (which is always a good practice)

Comment: So create the `var` in my view? before the script link to the external js?

Comment: @MikeBarwick yep if it works then you should create a config.js file to include in your html in which to define all js config var like this ;)